# undefined reference to `concatf'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have gone through similar questions and seen answers given, where given and none of those points me to what I am doing wrong. I keep getting undefined reference to 'concatf' while the function is properly defined in the header file.

concatf.c

```
#include "concatf.h"


/*
 * vscprintf:
 * MSVC implements this as _vscprintf, thus we just 'symlink' it here
 * GNU-C-compatible compilers do not implement this, thus we implement it here
 */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define vscprintf _vscprintf
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
int vscprintf(const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    va_list ap_copy;
    va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
    int retval = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, ap_copy);
    va_end(ap_copy);
    return retval;
}
#endif


int vasprintf(char **strp, const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    int len = vscprintf(format, ap);
    if (len == -1)
        return -1;
    char *str = (char*)malloc((size_t) len + 1);
    if (!str)
        return -1;
    int retval = vsnprintf(str, len + 1, format, ap);
    if (retval == -1) {
        free(str);
        return -1;
    }
    *strp = str;
    return retval;
}

int concatf(char **strp, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    int retval = vasprintf(strp, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return retval;
}
```

concatf.h

```
#ifndef CONCATF_H
#define CONCATF_H

#if defined(__GNUC__) && ! defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed for (v)asprintf, affects '#include <stdio.h>' */
#endif
#include <stdio.h>  /* needed for vsnprintf    */
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed for malloc, free */
#include <stdarg.h> /* needed for va_*         */

int concatf(char **strp, const char *format, ...);

#endif // CONCATF_H
```

build.c

```
#include "concatf.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char _binary_script_php_start;
extern char _binary_script_php_end;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // EXTRACT OUR RESOURCE OBJECT INTO /tmp/test.php
    char *p = &_binary_script_php_start;
    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/test.php","wb");
    while ( p != &_binary_script_php_end ) {
        fputc(*p++,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // NOW READ IN OUR STANDARD ARGUMENTS AND LAUNCH OUR COMMAND
    int i = 1;
    char *cmd = "php /tmp/test.php";
    char *s = NULL;
    // asprintf(&s, "%s",cmd);
    // for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    //     asprintf(&s, "%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    // }
    // concatf("%s",cmd);
    // for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    //     concatf("%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    // }
    concatf(&s, "%s",cmd);
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        concatf(&s, "%s \"%s\"",s,argv[i]);
    }
    system(s);
    free(s);
    unlink("/tmp/test.php"); // comment me out for debugging if you want
}
```

These codes run on my environment but fail to run on the second windows environment and those of my colleagues, I can't seem to point why that  is the case.
To run it you will need a php file named script.php run `ld -r -b binary script.php data.o` to complie your php file and `gcc build.c data.o -o runme` to link the php file with the build function. You can find the sample project here https://github.com/Sammiiie/C_php_http.

Comment: Where do you build with `concatf.c`?

Comment: And do you link it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried building with gcc conactf.c build.c data.o -o runme and I still got the undefined reference error

Comment: *"I keep getting undefined reference to 'concatf' while the function is properly defined in the header file."* - an undefined reference isn't a compile-time problem; it's a **link** time problem. It means the function declaration (header) is probably fine, but come link-time there's no "there" there. If this code is being compiled with a non-MS toolchain that doesn't surprise me, since `concatf` is clearly nestled in a `#ifdef _MSC_VER` preprocessor block and will thus only be formally defined in that circumstance. If that really is intentional, the header should probably be done the same way.

Comment: Unrelated, but that first `for()` loop gives me that willies...

Comment: @WhozCraig doing so gives me an `implicit declaration of function 'concatf'`.  It is nestled that way on purpose and un-nestling it still leaves me where I started with the undefined error

Comment: Why do you make `concatf` only available for the MSVC compiler? It's not a standard C function, it's not a POSIX function. Why use conditional compilation if you want to use it for all compilers?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Concatf was AsprintF on my code, asprinf is available on Linux that is why I did that. Now Like I stated the function runs on my environment but I can't get it to run on my colleagues, so I changed the function name and that allowed me to replicate the error he is getting.

Comment: You need conditional compilation for the `asprintf` function, since it exists on some systems but not others. However, `concatf` does not exist on any system which means you need to define it yourself everywhere, *without* conditional compilation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware and made that correction earlier and have edited my question to reflect that also.  It does not solve the problem. Like you said earlier it is a link error and I have tried linking `concatf.c`, `build.c` and `data.o` and I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to scale back your example code, and include (in your question) the command with all files. Create a proper [mre], without the PHP file and the resource extraction. A Simple `int main(void) { char *s = NULL; concatf(&s, "%s", "foo"); }` would be enough. Try to simplify the `concatf.h` and `concatf.c` files to their absolute minimum needed. The `concatf` function itself could just be empty and not do anything at all (besides `return 0;`).

Comment: When you get the extremely simple example to build, link and run properly, then you can start to add more details. Step by step, building, linking and testing between each single small and simple step.